# Removing lines from file based on character/word ratio - unix/bash

Tags: python, unix, count, word-count, charactercount

I have two files and I need to remove lines that falls under a certain token ratio, e.g.

File 1:

```
This is a foo bar question
that is not a parallel sentence because it's too long
hello world
```

File 2:

```
c'est le foo bar question
creme bulee
bonjour tout le monde
```

And the ratio calculated is total `no. of words in file 1 / total no. of words in file 2` and the sentences are removed if it falls under this ratio.

Then the output is a conjoined file with sentences from file1 and file2 separated with tab:

[out]:

```
This is a foo bar question\tc'est le foo bar question
hello world\tbonjour tout le monde
```

The files have always the same number of lines. I have been doing it as followed but **how to do the same in unix bash instead of using python?**

```
# Calculate the ratio.
with io.open('file1', , 'r', encoding='utf8') as f1, io.open('file2', , 'r', encoding='utf8') as f2: 
    ratio = len(f1.read().split()) / float(len(f2.read().split()))
# Check and output to file.
with io.open('file1', , 'r', encoding='utf8') as f1, io.open('file2', , 'r', encoding='utf8') as f2, io.open('fileout', , 'w', encoding='utf8') as fout:
    for l1, l2 in zip(file1, file2):
        if len(l1.split())/float(len(l2.split())) > ratio:
            print>>fout, "\t".join([l1.strip() / l2.strip()])
```

Also, if the **ratio calculation is based on characters instead of words**, I can do this in python but **how do i achieve the same in unix bash**? Note that the difference is only counting with `len(str.split())` and `len(str)`.

```
# Calculate the ratio.
with io.open('file1', , 'r', encoding='utf8') as f1, io.open('file2', , 'r', encoding='utf8') as f2: 
    ratio = len(f1.read()) / float(len(f2.read()))
# Check and output to file.
with io.open('file1', , 'r', encoding='utf8') as f1, io.open('file2', , 'r', encoding='utf8') as f2, io.open('fileout', , 'w', encoding='utf8') as fout:
    for l1, l2 in zip(file1, file2):
        if len(l1)/float(len(l2)) > ratio:
            print>>fout, "\t".join([l1.strip() / l2.strip()])
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'in unix'? In bash script or some other programming language?

Comment: Bash is generally not a particularly good platform for non-integer arithmetic.  This is easy to work around with a simple Awk helper script, but if you already have a working Python implementation, why bother?

Comment: You misspelled crème brûlée.

Comment: `[l1.strip() / l2.strip()]` is not valid. You might mean: `[l1.strip(), l2.strip()]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple ratio calculator in Awk.

```
awk 'NR == FNR { a[NR] = NF; next }
    { print NF/a[FNR] }' file1 file2
```

This merely prints the ratio for each line.  Extending it to only print the second file when the ratio is in a particular range is easy.

```
awk 'NR == FNR { a[NR] = NF; next }
    NF/a[FNR] >= 0.5 && NF/a[FNR] <= 2' file1 file2
```

(This uses an Awk shorthand -- in the general form `condition { action }` if you omit the `{ action }` it defaults to `{ print }`.  Similarly if you omit the condition, the action is taken unconditionally.)

You could run a second pass over `file1` to do the same, or just run it again with the file names inverted.

Oh, wait, here is a complete solution.

```
awk 'NR == FNR { a[NR] = NF; w[NR] = $0; next }
    NF/a[FNR] >= 0.5 && NF/a[FNR] <= 2 { print w[FNR] "\t" $0 }' file1 file2
```

Comment: also, inverting the files won't really work since the ratio would have been also inverted in the 2nd run =(

Comment: You haven't documented what ratios you actually use, but you'll note that I made it symmetric quite on purpose.  I use 2 as the factor; so if the ratio exceeds 2 or [if it's less than](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97324/antonym-for-exceed) the inverse -- i.e. 1/2 == 0.5 -- an entry is excluded.  This means you *can* invert the file names in this scenario.

Comment: While translated texts tend to be longer than the source text, there are inevitably situations where a competent translator will choose a shorter idiomatic expression in the target language.  I don't speak French but I suppose "dead-end street" vs "cul-de-sac" could be an example.

Comment: My apologies -- syntax error fixed.  (`>=` pro `=>`, duh.)

Answer (score 1):

tripleee's comment that bash is not good for non-integer is correct, but if you really want to do bash this should get you started.  You could do it with the program `wc` and the `-w` argument.  It counts words. bc does float division among other things.

```
while read line1 <&3 && read line2 <&4; do     
    line1_count=`echo $line1 | wc -w`
    line2_count=`echo $line2 | wc -w`
    ratio=`echo "$line1_count / $line2_count" | bc -l`
    echo $ratio
done 3<file1 4<file2
```

Also, `man bc` and look at the part about relational expressions.  That should allow you to do the comparison to whatever your threshold is for the ratio.

Comment: If you have a simple integer ratio then you could get by with simple integer arithmetic.  For a ratio of 2: If splitting `line1` into tokens twice exceeds the number of tokens in `line2` or vice versa, skip this pair.  So `creme brulee creme brulee` (4 tokens) is still less than the 10 tokens of the English sentence it's paired with, but when you do the inverse comparison, 20 tokens is definitely more than the 2 in the French sentence; so we skip this pair.

Comment: You could use Bash arrays, or just split into `$*`.  Like `set -- $line1; tok1=$#; set -- $line1 line1; tok1_2=$#; set -- $line2; tok2=$#; set -- $line2 $line2; tok2_2=$#; if [ $tok1_2 -gt $tok2 ] || [ $tok2_2 -gt $tok1 ]; then continue; fi`